# Eclipse view for Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()

Tags: java, eclipse

Good evening,

I would like to see the stack trace when debugging java under Eclipse. For now, I go to the view "Expressions" and check the object returned by the following method:

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

Is there a view in Eclipse that does the same job?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the stack is displayed in the `Debug` view.

In case it isn't visible, you can reopen it from the `Window->Show View` menu, which should contain a `Debug` item.

If you want the usual text output rather than the GUI display, you can obtain it by copying an item from the `Debug` view. It will put the stack starting from the selected item into your clipboard.